# downloading file vs creating file on client side javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

requirement - download a particular file on user action .
We can create files on client side using FILE API. So I am creating a file on client side from the data which is received from server so that user can download the file . 
There is one more approach to do this that is getting file generated at server side and getting URL to the file instead of sending the file data.
 I want to know  which approach is better in terms of security and performance ? sending file data from server or sending a file URL from server?

Comment: Really depends on your usecase.    
Security is the same either way more or less.    

Performance:    
Clientside generation = Less server resouces needed.     
But might be really slow for Mobile browsers.    

Server side = Able to cache result.    
Which means if 100 people are trying to download same file, you allready have result and can quicker give them the download.

Comment: If all the data needed is already on the server, it's easiest to just create the file there and send an url. Prevents users from messing with the file creation. So unless there's an argument to create it client side, i'd stick with the server for this.